# rotating android screen causes ListFragment to show progress indicator

Tags: android, android-orientation

In a FragmentActivity I've put a ListFragment.

When I rotate the screen I'm getting an hourglass underneath the listview as picture and it never goes away until I quit the whole activity.

The fault is to do with the listadapter and what it says about setListShown() showing the progress bar, but I've no idea how to fix it.

If I add retainInstance(true) after creating my fragment:

```
    GuideListFragment guideListFragment = new GuideListFragment();
    guideListFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
```

Then if I only add my initial fragment during onCreate if savedInstanceState is null then the hourglass goes away, however all animations assigned in my backstack fail and the manual for setRetainInstance explicitly states not to use this method if using the backstack.

How do I fix this? I've attached code if it helps.

thanks.

[image]

```
public class GuideListActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    private GuideAdapter<? extends Identifiable> guideAdapter;

    private List<Guide> guideItems;
    private List<Topic> topicItems;
    private List<SubTopic> subTopicItems;

    private DataManager dataManager;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private static final String GUIDE_FRAGMENT = "GUIDE";
    private static final String TOPIC_FRAGMENT = "TOPIC";
    private static final String SUBTOPIC_FRAGMENT = "SUBTOPIC";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, false, false);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_guide_list);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        dataManager = DatabaseApplication.getInstance().getDataManager();

        addFragment(GUIDE_FRAGMENT, Identifiable.INVALID_ID);
    }

    private void addFragment(@Nonnull final String fragmentTag,
            final long parentId) {

        GuideListFragment guideListFragment = new GuideListFragment();

        if (fragmentTag.equals(GUIDE_FRAGMENT)) {
            guideItems = dataManager.getAllGuides();
            guideAdapter = new GuideAdapter<Guide>(this, guideItems);

        } else if (fragmentTag.equals(TOPIC_FRAGMENT)) {
            topicItems = dataManager.getAllTopicsForGuide(parentId);
            guideAdapter = new GuideAdapter<Topic>(this, topicItems);
            Guide g = dataManager.getGuide(parentId);

        } else if (fragmentTag.equals(SUBTOPIC_FRAGMENT)) {
            subTopicItems = dataManager.getAllSubTopicsForTopic(parentId);
            guideAdapter = new GuideAdapter<SubTopic>(this, subTopicItems);
            Topic t = dataManager.getTopic(parentId);

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "addFragment with empty type");
            return;
        }

        guideItems = dataManager.getAllGuides();
        guideAdapter = new GuideAdapter<Guide>(this, guideItems);

        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        guideListFragment.setListAdapter(guideAdapter);

        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_in,
                R.anim.fragment_out, R.anim.fragment_in_backstack, R.anim.fragment_out_backstack);

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.guidelist_container, guideListFragment,
                fragmentTag);

        addTransactionToBackStack(fragmentTag);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    private void addTransactionToBackStack(@Nonnull final String fragmentTag) {

        Fragment prev = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
        if (prev != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.remove(prev);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGuideSelected(long id, @Nonnull final String fragmentTag) {
        if (fragmentTag.equals(GUIDE_FRAGMENT)) {
            addFragment(TOPIC_FRAGMENT, id);
        } else if (fragmentTag.equals(TOPIC_FRAGMENT)) {
            addFragment(SUBTOPIC_FRAGMENT, id);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The manual says this so I guess my problem is something to do with this but I've no idea how to fix it: "The default behavior of ListFragment is to start with the list not being shown, only showing it once an adapter is given with setListAdapter(ListAdapter). If the list at that point had not been shown, when it does get shown it will be do without the user ever seeing the hidden state."

Comment: In my experience a screen rotate causes an onPause/onResume which would explain the reloading of data.

Comment: Yes, but something is causing the progress bar to be permanently shown on screen, following what the manual says about setListShown(), and I've no idea how to fix it. I've updated my main post, btw.